# How do I convert a .avi file to a .flv file?

Tags: video, conversion, flash, web

I've been sent a .avi file that I need to convert to flash format to put online. What free software is there that will do this? I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 to work with so any software for either system will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/).

example:

```
/path/to/ffmpeg -i input.avi -f flv output.flv
```

Answer (score 11):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is very good and works on Windows.

You'll need something like:

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.avi -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -f flv file.flv
```

Comment: windows builds (so you don't have to *try* and compile it yourself): http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [John T](https://superuser.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-convert-a-avi-file-to-a-flv-file/26176#26176), [mlambie](https://superuser.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-convert-a-avi-file-to-a-flv-file/26178#26178) and [Chealion](https://superuser.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-convert-a-avi-file-to-a-flv-file/26180#26180)'s answers, and if you're not so keen on the command line, I would recommend you to try [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html), which is actually a GUI on top of ffmpeg (and other encoders).

Answer (score 1):

[Media Coder (Windows)](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) is another good encoder - it covers a lot of file formats in both audio and video.

There's only one downside, though: the main interface isn't user-friendly. If you think this one does the job for you, ensure you make use of its browser-based wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific codec or does it matter which one is used?

Flash video can use one of three codecs:

- H.264 (Flash 9 Release 3 or newer)
- On2VP6 (Flash 7 or newer)
- Sorenson Spark (Flash 6 or newer)

You can convert into all 3 using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and there are several GUIs available to handle the conversion using ffmpeg.

If you want to use Ubuntu you'll want to install ffmpeg first check out the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg)

Once it's installed you can use a command such as:

```
/path/to/ffmpeg -i input.avi -ar 22050 -ab 96 -b 1200 -r 12 -f flv -s 320x240 -acodec mp3 -ac 1 output.flv
```

-ar = Audio rate
-ab = Audio bit rate
-b = bitrate
-s = size
-acodec = audio codec
-f = format

If you're more comfortable using a GUI with Windows you can try a variety of GUI frontends such as [MeWiG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mewig/) or [AVANTI](http://avanti.arrozcru.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) is very good

Comment: haha.. when you don't capitalize it, it sounds like you're referring to any old converter (most of which are crap).
http://download.cnet.com/Any-Video-Converter/3000-2194_4-10661456.html

Comment: Yes. LoL it is actually a program. I have used it for a while now and I convert all my youtube videos with it